# What do you call a metaphor that describes the opposite of what a thing is?

Tags: creative-writing, metaphor

What do you call a metaphor that describes the opposite of what a thing is? Let's say you describe metaphorically the stagnant air in the room as a colorful festival brimming with sounds and laughter, or you describe the silence in a dark room as a fiery battle between two large armies in the middle of a summer day? Does that make sense, and when should you do this and towards what aim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Verbal Irony** From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irony

as soft as concrete or as clear as mud

or comedic irony? “The ships hung in the sky in much the same way that bricks don't.” D. Adams.